# Preventing "MATLAB:unassignedOutputs" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I'm looking to both catch and handle the "unassignedOuputs" error in Matlab. More specifically, looking at the following code:

```
try
    [out1,out2]= somefunction(in1,in2);
catch err
    if strcmp(err.identifier,'MATLAB:unassignedOutputs')
        <some code>
    else
        rethrow(err);
    end
end
```

If "somefunction" does not assign out2 and the resulting error is caught, is it possible to somehow retrieve the rest of the outputs from the function (in this case out1)? If not, is there a way to re-call the function ignoring that value so the function will not throw the error?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Typically using nargout solves such issues.

Comment: I am trying to essentially check if the function I am calling ("somefunction" in the example above) defines all of the outputs it needs to. If it does not, I want to still run the function, collect all the other outputs, and identify which output was not correctly assigned.

Comment: Then use nargout to get the number of outputs

Comment: I am personally struggling to understand the use case here.  If it's a function you wrote, use stuff like `varargout` and `nargout` as already mentioned.  If it's not a function you wrote, don't you already have to check what outputs it requires in order to use it? If you just want to ignore one of the outputs, use ~

Comment: @nkjt Sorry I'll be more specific. It is not a function I wrote, and I do know the number of outputs. However, I cannot guarantee that the user defined all the outputs themselves (the user in this case is a student). In the case that an output was not defined, I want to catch that and display my own warning (i.e. "You didn't define output X"). This way, I can still get the rest of the outputs of the function and continue without an error interruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to retrieve variables once the function has been terminated with this error. For the case when the *first* output is produced but not the second, you could retry it with just one output, naively something like:

```
try
    [out1,out2]= somefunction(in1,in2);
catch err
    if strcmp(err.identifier,'MATLAB:unassignedOutputs')
         try
             out2 = [];
             out1 = somefunction(in1, in2);
         catch err2
             % rethrow original error
             rethrow(err)
         end
    else
        rethrow(err);
    end
end
```

To display a message saying which output wasn't assigned, you'd have to parse `err.message` (although the default message itself should be reasonably clear).

But getting this to work if you have more than two outputs, and you don't know which might have not been properly defined, would not be simple.  And if the first output is not defined, this won't work at all.  In that case you would have to, I think, edit the function itself.

If the specific use case is checking a bunch of student codes which all take the same inputs and provide the same outputs, an alternative option would be to provide them with a function template which contains a check at the end if the outputs exist, and if not sets them to empty and displays your custom message.

Comment: I was afraid there might not be a way to do this with multiple outputs. Thanks for the detailed answer.